Robocopy more skipped than total files?
I used robocopy to copy a directory over an existing one on my backup drive, and got some really weird output:  
Command used:
robocopy S:\ "Z:\Backup\S" *.* /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:DAT /MIR /MT:16 > D:\BackupLogs\robocopy_S_to_Z.log


S does not contain symlinks
S does not contain any "cloud folders" like OneDrive, Dropbox, ...

How can it be that it skipped more files than there are total files, also skipping more bytes than there are total bytes?
What could be the reason?

What command was run? Does robocopy count symlinks as skipped, copying the physical file, but not count the symlinks for total file enumeration? How does it treat locally unavailable OneDrive files (if that's even applicable - command would verify)? Please don't screenshot terminal output - instead, please copy/paste into a code box (if wanting to highlight like in the screenshot, you'll need to use HTML code and not code fences).
